# Q: Reading and display string from a serial port in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to develop a serial tool use UWP,and I have a problem to block my develop. when I receive a string buffer from serial, I want to display it, so i want to show I on TextBlock,but when I refresh textBlock use `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`,textblock will show receive string,but when serial string receive more and more, the app refresh textblock will being very slow and influence app running, and this problem will be more and more severity. I think it slowly because I refresh Textblock String
become more and more to refresh,so is there any way to solve my problem?

I have try to use like `<list><textBlock></list>` to show string,it can fresh faster than `<textBlock>`, but it can no select text from one textblock list to another textblock list, so it can't satisfy me.

below is my code:

```
loadAsyncTask = DataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(cancellationToken);
UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
    if (bytesRead > 0){
         string inputStr = DataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
         ReadBytesCounter += bytesRead;
         this.serialVM.serialInputStr += inputStr;
    }
```

and xaml code like
`<TextBlock x:Name="xTB_SerialRec" IsTextSelectionEnabled="True" Text="{x:Bind serialVM.serialInputStr, Mode=TwoWay}" />`

Comment: I simulated the text changing with timer, it could update the `TextBlock` quickly with above code, it looks the problem occurs from serial reading, can you try to print the string in the output window check if it has correct value?

Comment: i can sure i reading data from serial is right, i send it from my python program for test. but, maybe i can use timer test my uwp program too.  and there is a point that serial input data is more and more,  update textblock presure will alse up,and refresh is slowly than start

Comment: Can you output the serial read rate?